# Getting a weird error, I'm using cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Im getting This Error Instance method '-setTouchEnabled:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
I don't know whats causing it, any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Heres my code sorry if its messy

```
- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"start.png"];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player];
        [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:0.5];
        [self setTouchEnabled:YES];
        _monsters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // stuff that needs updating
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
        //labels
        StrategyBullet = 10;
        Strategyscore = 0;
        CCLabelTTF *label2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Ninja stars " fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:15];

        label2.position = ccp(400,310);

        label2.color = ccc3(255, 0, 0);

        [self addChild: label2 z:1];

        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Score" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:15];

        label.position = ccp(30,310);

        label.color = ccc3(255, 0, 0);

        [self addChild: label z:1];

        StrategyscoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14];
        StrategyscoreLabel.position = ccp(65, 310);
        StrategyscoreLabel.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
        [self addChild:StrategyscoreLabel z:1];

        StrategyBulletLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:14];
        StrategyBulletLabel.position = ccp(450, 310);
        StrategyBulletLabel.color = ccc3(255, 255, 255);
        [self addChild:StrategyBulletLabel z:1];



    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Your class inherits from what?

Comment: What is this class ? Does it extend CCLayer ?

Comment: Also what version of Cocos2D you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter you're looking for would look like this.-

```
[self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];
```

(notice the missing 'Is'). Or you can directly write

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

**EDIT**

As @Grzegorz Krukowski said, `setIsTouchEnabled` is currently deprecated and `setTouchEnabled` is actually the method used in `cocos2d 2.x`. My guess is that you may be using a version prior 2.x.

Comment: setIsTouchEnabled was deprecated in newest Cocos2D version so I don't think it's right solution

Comment: Ups, you're right. Anyway, if `setTouchEnabled` is not found, chances are that cocos2d version used here is not the newest, though.

Comment: As far as i know im using cocos2d 2.x but i will reinstall it later, thanks